# Buscador en administrador de Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-admin

En el administrador de django hay alguna forma de habilitar un buscador?

Tiene habilitado un botón para agregar un registro, pero cuando estos registros son demasiados, es muy tardado encontrar un registro para modificar o eliminar. En la imagen se muestran 14 mil registros, lo hace que sea  tardado encotrar (X) registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a suponer que tu modelo es Parte  con los atributos `parte` , `activo` y `descripcion`. Para habilitar el buscador y filtros ve al archivo 'admin.py' que se encuentra en la carpeta de tu aplicación y escribe el siguiente código:

```
class ParteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # con esto muestras los campos que deses al mostrar la lista en admin
    list_display=['parte', 'activo']
    # con esto añades un campo de texto que te permite realizar la busqueda, puedes añadir mas de un atributo por el cual se filtrará
    search_fields = ['parte', 'descripcion']
    # con esto añadiras una lista desplegable con la que podras filtrar (activo es un atributo booleano)
    list_filter = ['activo']
```

al final del archivo `admin.py` tienes que registrar tu modelo personalizado

```
 admin.site.register(Parte, ParteAdmin)
```

el primer parámetro es el el modelo y el segundo la clase que acabamos de hacer

Answer (score 0):

Usa `search_fields` para habilitar la caja de búsqueda en el admin.

Ejemplo:

```
...
search_fields = ['nombre', 'apellido']
...
```

Tambien puedes buscar en un objeto relacionado via `ForeignKey` o `ManyToManyField` usando:

```
search_fields = ['user__email', ]
```

[Documentos oficiales de django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields)